# Adding reference to external .dll on Linux

Tags: dll, f#, mono, reference

I'm building an F# application with Mono on a Linux box but need to reference a DLL from the F# Power Pack.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding references on Mono works exactly the same way as on Windows. You just need to download PowerPack (there is a [ZIP download](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/releases/view/45593), which can be extracted on Linux). When building your F# application from the command line, you just specify the reference:

```
mono <fsharp-path>/fsc.exe 
  --resident 
  -r:<powerpack-path>/FSharp.PowerPack.dll 
  input.fs
```

This should work just fine (Note the `--resident` option, which starts F# compiler process in the background and so it makes F# compiler on Mono faster, because it isn't JITted again each time it starts).